# PHP fgets(): read of 8192 with errno=5 I/O

Tags: php, phar

I'm trying to execute a .phar file using PHP. There was no issue when using PHP 8.1, but when i started to use 8.2.1, i get some output and after 5-6 lines showed, i get following error:

> Notice: fgets(): Read of 8192 bytes failed with errno=5 I/O error in phar:///data/data/com.termux/files/home/PocketMine-MP.phar/src/console/ConsoleReader.php on line 67

This issue does not happen when i use cmd on Windows.

Then the process kills itself.

I have no idea whats causing it since it all worked in the older PHP version

Comment: It is a known issue in usage with Vagrant or other virtualizations. Do you use such?

Comment: No i dont use any virtualization

Comment: `since it all worked in the older PHP version` did you follow the upgrade steps as to what has been deprecated and backward incompatible changes, [doc](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration82.php)

Comment: Also check if you are using any packages or dependencies which are not compatible with PHP 8.2.1?

Comment: According to my quick googling, that's some application to create Minecraft servers. You can't generally run PHP apps in versions that they are not designed to run on, and we could help you fix _your_ code but this is more a support request for a third-party application.

Comment: as i said it all worked fine. i know it is not designed for Android but it did work. And it also works via Windows CMD using ADB shell

Comment: You didn't understand me. If the application was written and tested on PHP/8.1, there's no guarantee that it'll run on PHP/8.2, or PHP/8.3, or PHP/15.2. Programming languages often make backward incompatible changes and PHP is an interpreted language so you can't even compile it in an old version on the engine and run it. You need to identify the issue, fix it in the source code and generate a new Phar archive. Is that an option?

Answer (score 1):

Issue was fixed after using https://github.com/pmmp/musl-cross-make.
Seems like some libc calls are blacklisted by Android.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).